# npm install fails with ChromeDriver installation failed error

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, proxy, dockerfile

Im building the vue.js application using docker as follows

```
# build stage
FROM node:10.15.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
.
.
.
```

Since this in this environment there is no internet, I have added proxy as below, after the `COPY` command.

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://<proxy-ip>:3128
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://<proxy-ip>:3128
ENV http_proxy http://<proxy-ip>:3128
ENV https_proxy http://<proxy-ip>:3128
```

But still it seems to be not able to connect to internet fully, Below is the error I get during the npm install step,
[image]

I have tried changing the proxy configurations as follows, But still the issue is same

```
RUN npm config set proxy http://<proxy-ip>:3128
RUN npm config set http-proxy http://<proxy-ip>:3128
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy-ip>:3128
```